# Creating a generic array at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Is there a way in c# to do something like this:

```cs
public void Foo<T>()
{
    T[] arr = Goo() as T[];
}
```

Where Goo returns an `object[]`, Using reflection or whatever?

Comment: I don't think an `object[]` could ever be a `T[]`. An `object` could be though.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: [Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Two: Array Covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)

Comment: @Ani - I could be misreading that, but it seems to say that `object[] a = new T[]` will be valid (`where T:class`), not the other way around.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it depends on what the `object[]` *actually is* ;p Since `T[]` can be represented as an `object[]`, it is possible that your `object[]` is actually a `T[]`. However, if the array is *constructed* as an `object[]` but happens to *contain* all `T`, then indeed: the cast will fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
public void Foo<T>()
{
    T[] arr = Goo().OfType<T>().ToArray();
}
```

In your example you are casting the `object[]` to `T[]` which will also work if the two types match exactly:

```
public void Foo<T>()
{
    T[] arr = Goo() as T[];
    if (arr != null)
    {
        // use the array
    }
}
```

For example this will work in the following case:

```
public object[] Goo()
{
    return new string[] { "a", "b" };
}
```

and then calling Foo like this:

```
Foo<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest and most reliable approach is to copy the array, doing the cast item-by-item:

```
public void Foo<T>()
{
    T[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(Goo(), x => (T)x);
}
```

This is an "`unbox.any`", which means (to the JIT):

- do a `castclass` (i.e. reference-preserving type-check) if `T` turns out to be reference-type
- do an `unbox` if `T` turns out to be value-type

---

Arrays of reference-types are *covariant*, meaning that a `T[]` can be *represented* as an `object[]`. Because of this, there is a chance that the result of `Goo()` *is* actually a `T[]`. We might also want to test this:

```
public T[] Foo<T>()
{
    var tmp = Goo();
    T[] arr = tmp as T[];
    if(arr == null && tmp != null) {
        arr = Array.ConvertAll(Goo(), x => (T)x);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

One annoyance of this though is that we now have different semantics - in some cases it is the same array, in some cases it is copied. This could be problematic if we *mutate* the array.

Comment: Hmm ... you have `void` in the signature, yet you return the array? Shouldn't it have a `T[]` as a return type?

Comment: @Nocitus yup; the danger of coding on a 'phone :)